# Why is my ListView duplicating values when querying Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying Firestore using a listener to get the list of groups that the current user is a part of. I then display those groups using a simple ListView.

The problem is that the number of groups displayed is being duplicated. In the most recent test I did, the current user was part of 3 groups (named 1, 2, and 3). I then ran the `_createGroupDialog()` to create another. After it successfully creates the group, the app navigates to the group chat for that group. But when I hit the back button to go back to the list of groups, there were 11 entries! There should have only been 4! Why did the ListView show me 11 entries?

**What I saw:**
3
2
1
3
4
2
1
2
3
4
1

**What I should have seen:**
1
2
3
4

**The code (I removed a lot of unecessary code):**

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget { //My Groups screen
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  var groups = [];
  var tempGroupsList = [];
  var tempGroupDataList = [];
  final groupNameController = TextEditingController();
  final database = Database();
  String username = '';
  String tempUsername = '';
  String uid = '';
  String tempUID = '';
  var groupsListener;
  var lastReadTimestampListener;
  var groupChatListener;
  late Stream<QuerySnapshot> groupsStream;
  bool eventHappened = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    groupsListener.cancel();
    groupChatListener.cancel();
    lastReadTimestampListener.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    tempUID = await database.getUID();
    tempUsername = await database.getUsername();

    getGroupsListener();
  }

  void getGroupsListener() async { 
    await globals.userGlobals(); //Required if using globals
    final groupsCollectionPath = globals.groupsCollection();
    groupsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(groupsCollectionPath).snapshots();

    groupsListener = groupsStream.listen((event) {
      tempGroupsList = [];
      groups = [];

      for (var doc in event.docs) {
        tempGroupsList.add(doc.id);
      }

      //Using the list of group IDs in tempGroupsList, query the group info from the main groups record
      tempGroupsList.forEach((element) async {
        final groupData = await database.getGroupInfo(groupID: element);
        tempGroupDataList.add(groupData);
      });

      setState(() {
        //update the UI...
        groups = tempGroupDataList;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<void> _createGroupDialog(BuildContext context) {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Create Group'),
            content: TextField(
                controller: groupNameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Group Name',
                )
            ),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    if (groupNameController.text.isNotEmpty) {
                      final groupID = await database.createGroup(groupName: groupNameController.text);
                      if (groupID == '') {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Error creating group');
                      } else {
                        groupNameController.clear();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop(); //Close the dialog box
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenChat(groupID: groupID,)),
                        );
                      }
                    } else {
                      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: 'Enter a group name');
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('OK')
              ),
              TextButton(onPressed: () {Navigator.of(context).pop();}, child: Text('Cancel')),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(26, 26, 26, 1.0),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Groups'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(39, 38, 38, 1.0),
        elevation: 0.0,
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton( 
              onPressed: () {
                _createGroupDialog(context);
              },
              child: Icon(Icons.add)
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: groups.length ?? 0,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final group = ModelMainGroup.fromJson(groups[index]);
                final groupName = group.groupName;
                final groupID = group.groupID;

                return GestureDetector(
                  child: groupWidget(groupName, groupID, false),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenChat(groupID: groupID,)),);
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: do not call this `groupsStream.listen((event) { ...` - if you have a `Stream` then use specialized `StreamBuilder` widget instead

Comment: Agree with @pskink.

Comment: @pskink I'm trying to use StreamBuilder but the challenging part is that the stream is listening to a collection to get some IDs, then I need to use those IDs in a different query to get the information that'll be displayed in the ListView. So it's a 2-step process just to display a single ListView.

Comment: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams#modify-stream-methods

Comment: @pskink so `expand()` is the one I want to use?

Comment: I would say `asyncMap` but for learning something new try all of them

Comment: also you can use `await for`, more here: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams#transforming-an-existing-stream

Comment: @pskink it seems like this is definitely the right track. I think the next challenge is finding the function that will let me output a `const` widget to the `builder` section of `StreamBuilder`.

Comment: @pskink Do I need to create a second stream from what I'm trying to do? In theory, I think I might only need 1 because the "stream part" is the part that I want in real-time. Then I need to query Firestore to get the final information - that second part doesn't need to be a stream, right?

Comment: That's why I said to use `asyncMap` - it's callback returns a simple value or a future

Comment: @pskink I don't get how to use asyncMap. Can you help me out?

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/speed-up-dart-flutter-with-futures-streams-and-streamtransformers-77ff5a20daa3